# TypeError: contacts.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, api, react

Olá, pesquisei sobre o assunto e vi que pode ser erro que pode ser por conta de não estar recebendo um array. Porém, coloquei pra ser retornado um array na API, pode ser consultado aqui
https://agendaapplp3.herokuapp.com/contatos

só que na parte do react aparece esse erro, `"TypeError: contacts.map is not a function"`.
segue o código:

```
   const ListContacts: React.FC = () => {
  
   const [contacts, setContacts] = useState <ContactsProps[]>([]);

   async function getContacts(){
       const response = await api.get<ContactsProps[]>("/contatos");
      setContacts(response.data);
   }
   useEffect(()=>{
       getContacts();
   },[]);
```

o erro está nessa parte abaixo.

```
{contacts.map((contact)=>(
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{contact.id}</td>
                                    <td>{contact.nome}</td>
                                    <td>{contact.email}</td>
                                    <td>{contact.telefone}</td>
                                    <td>{contact.idlocal}</td>
                                    <td>{contact.idtipocontato}</td>
                                </tr>
```

para se conectar a api, utilizei o axios

```
    import axios from "axios";

    const api = axios.create({
     baseURL:"https://agendaapplp3.herokuapp.com"
    })

    export default api;
```

sou novo em React, o que pode ser?

Comment: Voce nao deveria colocar no seu `setContacts` como `response.data.results`? pois ai sim seu `results` e um array.

Comment: coloquei e me apareceu isso Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ContactsProps[]'.  TS2339
Se adianta de algo, meu ContactsProps[] está assim:
interface ContactsProps{
    id:number;
    nome:string;
    email:string;
    telefone:string;
    idlocal:number;
    idtipocontato:number;
 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi seu problema, eu acho, colocando uma `interface` para o `Response`, e no `setContacts` colocamos `response.data.results`. Desta forma:

```
interface ContactsProps {
  id: number;
  nome: string;
  email: string;
  telefone: string;
  idlocal: number;
  idtipocontato: number;
}

interface Response { // Uma interface para o Response.
  data: {
    results: [];
  };
}

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://agendaapplp3.herokuapp.com',
});

const ListContacts: React.FC = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState<ContactsProps[]>([]);

  async function getContacts() {
    const response: Response = await api.get('/contatos'); // informamos ao TS que a resposta tera o formado do Response.

    setContacts(response.data.results); // set dos arrays para o contacts
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getContacts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
     <table>
      {contacts &&
        contacts.map((contact: ContactsProps) => (
          <tr key={Math.random()}>
            <td>{contact.id}</td>
            <td>{contact.nome}</td>
            <td>{contact.email}</td>
            <td>{contact.telefone}</td>
            <td>{contact.idlocal}</td>
            <td>{contact.idtipocontato}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
     </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default ListContacts;
```

Tente fazer os testes. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Caraca, resolveu mesmo, muito obrigado!
Mas poderia explicar? Como disse estou começando em react e por que do jeito que fiz estava errado?

Comment: nesse seu comentario anterior: `coloquei e me apareceu isso Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ContactsProps[]'. TS2339`, voce tentou atribuir a interface `ContactsProps` ao `response`?. Essa interface do `Response` nem era necessario, eu so coloque ela quando estava testando seu codigo e quando executei de primeira, funcionou. Mas explicando de uma maneira simples, a interface server pra voce `explicar` pro TS como vai ser a estrutura de um determinado objeto. Entao eu falei pro TS que o `response` teria a propriedade `data` e dentro de data teriamos o `results` do tipo array.

Comment: Entendi,  obrigado!